# How to implement instance sharing for case classes

Tags: class, scala, case-class

Assuming defintion:

```
case class IntegerWrapper(i : Int)
```

and being in a situation that potentially large amounts of `IntegerWrapper` instances with `i=[0..N>` may be created what does one have to do to:

1. Map this range to a fixed set of singletons `[IntegerWrapper(0) .. IntegerWrapper(N)>`
2. Preserve existing value semantics for class `IntegerWrapper` (matching, equals, hashcode, serialization)

I am looking to do instance sharing akin to what `java.lang.Integer` does. I guess my question is if this can be done without having to do everything myself. Simply defining a companion object with an `apply(i : Int)` does not compile. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
sealed trait IntegerWrapper {
  def i: Int
}

object IntegerWrapper extends (Int => IntegerWrapper) {
  private case class IntegerWrapperImpl(i: Int) extends IntegerWrapper

  private val instances: List[IntegerWrapperImpl] = ...
    /* Wrapper instances for i in [0..N) */

  def apply(i: Int): IntegerWrapper = instances(i)

  def unapply(iw: IntegerWrapper): Option[Int] = Some(iw.i)
}
```

The advantage is that `equals` and `hashCode` are still generated by the compiler, since `IntegerWrapperImpl` is a case class. The disadvantage is that you cannot directly use other compiler-added case class goodies, e.g., `copy`. If you want to use that, either expose `IntegerWrapperImpl` to the client, or, IMHO better, add `copy` to the `IntegerWrapper` interface.

Pattern matching works as usual:

```
val iw0 = IntegerWrapper(0)
val iw1: IntegerWrapper = IntegerWrapper(1)

iw0 match {
  case IntegerWrapper(0) => println("IW(0)")
  case _ => println("something else")
} // IW(0)

iw1 match {
  case IntegerWrapper(1) => println("IW(1)")
  case _ => println("something else")
} // IW(1)

iw1 match {
  case IntegerWrapper(2) => println("IW(2)")
  case _ => println("something else")
} // something else
```

Comment: Can you explain why this is better than making IntegerWrapper a plain class and adding my own companion object, unapply, equals, hashcode etc?

Comment: @SilvioBierman Exactly that you don't need to define ``equals``, ``hashCode`` etc yourself.

Comment: OK but does this not preclude pattern matching in IntegerWrapper?

Comment: @SilvioBierman You still need to define ``unapply`` (see my edited code), but that's it.

Comment: Don't forget to seal the `IntegerWrapper` trait!

Answer (score 6):

If you're just trying to avoid allocations, perhaps what you want is a [value class](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/value-classes.html)? In Scala 2.10, if your `IntegerWrapper` class extends `AnyVal`, instances usually won't get allocated, and instead static methods will be called on the value itself. For example:

```
scala> case class IntegerWrapper(val i: Int) extends AnyVal { def increment = i + 1 }
defined class IntegerWrapper

scala> object Test { IntegerWrapper(2).increment }
defined module Test

scala> :javap -verbose Test
...    
public Test$();
  Code:
   Stack=2, Locals=1, Args_size=1
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #13; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   aload_0
   5:   putstatic   #15; //Field MODULE$:LTest$;
   8:   getstatic   #20; //Field IntegerWrapper$.MODULE$:LIntegerWrapper$;
   11:  iconst_2
   12:  invokevirtual   #24; //Method IntegerWrapper$.extension$increment:(I)I
   15:  pop
   16:  return
```

Note that the extension method being called there is `Int => Int`.

For comparison, here's what you get if you don't extend `AnyVal`:

```
scala> :javap -verbose Test
...
public Test$();
  Code:
   Stack=3, Locals=1, Args_size=1
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #13; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   aload_0
   5:   putstatic   #15; //Field MODULE$:LTest$;
   8:   new #17; //class IntegerWrapper
   11:  dup
   12:  iconst_2
   13:  invokespecial   #20; //Method IntegerWrapper."<init>":(I)V
   16:  invokevirtual   #24; //Method IntegerWrapper.increment:()I
   19:  pop
   20:  return
```

With this version, you can see both the object allocation, and the call to a method of the new `IntegerWrapper` instance.

Comment: Very good to know so I accepted your answer. Unfortunately in my case IntegerValue extends a common trait RuntimeValue so extending AnyVal is not an option for me.

Comment: That's a pity - I don't think there's currently any way to mix a trait in with a value class. The only workaround I can think of is to write an implicit conversion from `IntegerValue` to `RuntimeValue` to get the `RuntimeValue` methods. And then of course you'll get `RuntimeValue` allocations each time...

Answer (score 4):

Memoize the results! With Scala, you can even abstract away all the required logic.

**The infrastructure you need:**

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

// A little memoization utility

object Memoization extends Memoization

trait Memoization {
  trait Memoizable[A] {
    def memoize(fun: A): A
  }

  implicit def fun1memoizable[A, B] = new Memoizable[A => B] {
    def memoize(f: A => B): (A => B) = new MemoizedFunction(f)
  }

  implicit def fun2memoizable[A, B, C] = new Memoizable[(A, B) => C] {
    def memoize(f: (A, B) => C): (A, B) => C = {
      val memo = new MemoizedFunction(f.tupled)
      (a, b) => memo((a, b))
    }
  }

  implicit def fun3memoizable[A, B, C, D] = new Memoizable[(A, B, C) => D] {
    def memoize(f: (A, B, C) => D): (A, B, C) => D = {
      val memo = new MemoizedFunction(f.tupled)
      (a, b, c) => memo((a, b, c))
    }
  }

  def memoize[F](f: F)(implicit m: Memoizable[F]): F = m memoize f

  class MemoizedFunction[-A, +B](f: A => B) extends (A => B) {
    private[this] val cache = collection.mutable.Map.empty[A, B]
    def apply(a: A): B = cache.getOrElseUpdate(a, f(a))
  }
}

import Memoization._

// Abstracting flyweight pattern 
// (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern)
trait Flyweight[Args, Obj] { self: (Args => Obj) =>
  val on: Args => Obj = memoize(this : (Args => Obj))
}

// Ctrl+D
```

**Usage:**

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

case class IntegerWrapper private(i: Int) {
  println(this.toString + " created.")
}

object IntegerWrapper extends (Int => IntegerWrapper) 
  with Flyweight[Int, IntegerWrapper]

// Ctrl+D

scala> IntegerWrapper.on(11)
IntegerWrapper(11) created.
res0: IntegerWrapper = IntegerWrapper(11)

scala> IntegerWrapper.on(11)
res1: IntegerWrapper = IntegerWrapper(11)
```

This is a general solution and uses a `Map`. You might be better off using a `Vector` for your particular case.

Comment: Perhaps the cache stored within `MemoizedFunction` could be of type
`collection.mutable.Map[A,WeakReference[B]]` (or `SoftReference[B]`) to avoid caching results in a way that prevents garbage collection of short-lived results? The mappings would unfortunately remain, but I can't think of a reliable way of using a WeakHashMap that fits with this generalised solution. A periodic/opportunistic purge of the map would be necessary.

Comment: Or one could use a Google Guava `CacheBuilder`. http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html

Comment: I have quite a code base that already builds on case class IntegerValue. Therefore I am looking for something that does not break existing code.

Comment: You can adapt this solution quite easily so that it does not break existing code.

Answer (score 3):

This is basically the same use case as for scala's `Symbol` class. So you could have a look at Symbol.scala as an inspiration for a reasonable implementation (in particular, an implementation that won't keep the IntegerWrapper instances in memory forever, even when not needed).

See https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_9_1_final/src//library/scala/Symbol.scala#L1

Comment: Interesting. I will look into that.